# Can I render a link with title and aria-label attributes using BeginField?

Tags: mvc

I'm using SXA 1.8 with Sitecore 9.1

For a cloned rendering - in my cshtml I need to conditionally wrap a list item in a link.  I have got the link part working, but I can't seem to add title and aria-label attributes?

This is what I've tried in my code:

```
@Html.Sitecore().BeginField("Link", item, new { haschildren=true, title=item.Fields["DescriptionLinkTitle"], @aria_label = item.Fields["DescriptionLinkTitle"] })
```

I'm trying not to resort to having something like

```
<a href="@url" title="@titlefield" aria-label="@titlefield">
  stuff
</a>
```

have also tried `@title`.

Note: The haschildren is just because I don't want the text of the link displayed.

The source output is just

```
<a href="/">
  stuff
</a>
```

So it seems to be ignoring the other attributes I'm trying to add.

Comment: Can you try to add .Value at the end of the fields? Example: item.Fields[“fieldname”].Value. Also, make sure the fields contains data and is published to Web

Comment: @HishaamNamooya that was it thanks.  I had actually tried .Value and was throwing an exception.  I swear I published everything, but today it published some new things and I added logic to check for null :)   Feel free to post as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: It would be better to change it to `item["DescriptionLinkTitle"]`, .Value will throw an exception if the field is empty (you'll need to add a null check) whereas this will just return an empty string

Comment: @jammykam good to know thanks! turns out I needed to publish AND spell my field correctly :D

Comment: @Jen comment converted to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both

```
item.Fields[“fieldName”].Value
```

Or as Jammykam mentioned

```
item[“fieldName”]
```

However, when using the `.Value`, you need to check for null and it will cause Null Exception if blank.

Finally, make sure that

1. The `FieldName`is properly set, i.e same as in Sitecore Template.
2. The item has been published to the `web` database

Comment: Your mention on mine is still wrong, it should be `item["fieldname"]`